# Why does this function only compute with python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, function

```
def monthly_gas_cost(days,miles,mpg,gas_cost):
    return '${} A month for gas'.format(miles/mpg*days*gas_cost)
```

I was making a simple function in python and had just used python not thinking, it had worked with

```
print(monthly_gas_cost(days=23,miles=4,mpg=30,gas_cost=2.87))
```

but when I try the line below it only does the computation with python 3. With python 2 it doesn't compute.

```
print(monthly_gas_cost(days=23,miles=12,mpg=20,gas_cost=2.87))
```

Comment: "it only works with python 3" --- what does this exactly mean? Does your computer shut down when you run it under python 2.7?

Comment: @zerkms doesn't complete the computation

Comment: "doesn't complete the computation" means "freezes forever", while you're observing something certainly different. Being clear in explaining the problem also helps yourself understand the problem in the very first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because division in Python 2 behaves differently, so use

```
from __future__ import division
```

in your Python 2 code

Comment: In particular, in Py2 the division operator `/` depends on the types if both the numerator and denominator are `int`s then it does integer division. In Py3, this is no longer true, `/` is always float division and you need to use the explicit integer division operator `//`. `from __future__ ...` brings Py3 behaviour to Py2.